# Codecademy BlackJack project

Tags: javascript, game, playing-cards

I've put in quite a bit of hours on this BlackJack project for Codecademy to get it to the point where I'm satisfied with it. Before I move on to create the UI for it I would really appreciate feedback on things to improve, such as my use of classes and objects, best practices, etc. I'm including a link to my jsFiddle.

[BlackJack project](http://jsfiddle.net/mrStevens/syB7P/15/)

```
"use strict";


// Hands for players, multiple hands used for splitting cards
function Hand() {
    var cards = [],
    // Set to true if totalScore > 21
    isBust = false,
    // Total of all cards at a point in time, aces are handled in calcTotalScore
    totalScore = 0;

    // Sets totalScore and isBust
    this.calcTotalScore = function () {
        var hasAce = false,
        tempCardValue;

        if (cards.length === 0) {
            console.log("ERROR: No cards in this Hand");
        } else {
            // Reset totalScore before every calculation
            totalScore = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
                tempCardValue = cards[i].getCardValue();
                if (tempCardValue === 11) { hasAce = true }
                totalScore += tempCardValue;
            }

            if ((totalScore > 21) && hasAce) {
                totalScore -= 10;
            }

            if (totalScore > 21) {
                isBust = true;
            }
        }
    }

    this.popLastCard = function () {
        var tempPoppedCard = cards.pop();
        this.calcTotalScore();

        return tempPoppedCard;
    };

    this.pushNewCard = function (card) {
        cards.push(card);
        this.calcTotalScore();
    };

    this.getScore = function () {
        return totalScore;
    };

    this.getCard = function (cardPos) {
        return cards[cardPos].getCardNumber() + " of " + cards[cardPos].getCardSuit();
    };

    this.getCardNumber = function (cardPos) {
        return cards[cardPos].getCardNumber();
    }

    this.getCardsLength = function () {
        return cards.length;
    }

    this.getIsBust = function () {
        return isBust;
    }
}


// Cards exist in Hands or Decks
function Card(inSuit, inNum) {
    this.getCardSuit = function () {
        var suitName = "";
        switch (inSuit) {
        case 1:
            suitName = "Hearts";
            break;
        case 2:
            suitName = "Clubs";
            break;
        case 3:
            suitName = "Diamonds";
            break;
        case 4:
            suitName = "Spades";
            break;
        default:
            suitName = "ERROR";
        }

        return suitName;
    };

    this.getCardNumber = function () {
        var numName = "";

        if (inNum === 1) {
            numName = "Ace";
        } else if (inNum > 10) {
            switch (inNum) {
            case 11:
                numName = "Jack";
                break;
            case 12:
                numName = "Queen";
                break;
            case 13:
                numName = "King";
                break;
            default:
                numName = "ERROR";
            }
        } else {
            numName = inNum;
        }

        return numName;
    };

    this.getCardValue = function () {
        var value = inNum > 9 ? 10 : inNum === 1 ? 11 : inNum;

        return value;
    };

}


// Decks used for shuffling and dealing cards to Hands
function Deck() {
    var deckOfCards = [];

    this.shuffle = function () {
        var tempCard,
        randomDeckIndex,
        tempCardSuit = 1,
        tempCardNumber = 1;

        deckOfCards.length = 0;

        // Populate deck with 52 cards in order
        for (var i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
            deckOfCards[i] = new Card(tempCardSuit, tempCardNumber);

            if (tempCardNumber < 13) {
                tempCardNumber++;
            } else {
                tempCardNumber = 1;
                tempCardSuit++;
            }
        }

        // Randomize the 52 cards
        for (var i = (deckOfCards.length - 1); i > 0; i--) {
            if (i === 0) {
                randomDeckIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * deckOfCards.length);
            } else {
                randomDeckIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
            }
            tempCard = deckOfCards[randomDeckIndex];
            deckOfCards[randomDeckIndex] = deckOfCards[i];
            deckOfCards[i] = tempCard;
        }
    };

    // Returns last card in the Deck
    this.popLastCard = function () {
        return deckOfCards.pop();
    };
}


// Players have Hands
function Player() {
    var hands = [new Hand()];

    this.initializePlayer= function () {
        hands.length = 0;
        this.addNewHand();
    }

    this.addNewHand = function () {
        hands.push(new Hand());
    };

    this.getScore = function (handIndex) {
        return hands[handIndex].getScore();
    };

    this.getCard = function (handIndex, cardIndex) {
        return hands[handIndex].getCard(cardIndex);
    };

    this.pushNewCard = function (handIndex, card) {
        hands[handIndex].pushNewCard(card);
    };

    this.popLastCard = function (handIndex) {
        return hands[handIndex].popLastCard();
    }

    this.getCardNumber = function (handIndex, cardIndex) {
        return hands[handIndex].getCardNumber(cardIndex);
    }

    this.splitHand = function (handIndex) {
        this.addNewHand();
        hands[handIndex + 1].pushNewCard(hands[handIndex].popLastCard());
    }

    this.getHandsLength = function () {
        return hands.length;
    }

    this.getCardsLength = function (handIndex) {
        return hands[handIndex].getCardsLength();
    }

    this.getIsBust = function (handIndex) {
        return hands[handIndex].getIsBust();
    }

    this.getIsStand = function (handIndex) {
        return hands[handIndex].isStand;
    }

    this.setIsStand = function (handIndex) {
        hands[handIndex].isStand = true;
    }

    // Returns true if there are Hands left to play
    this.hasGoodHand = function () {
        var goodHand = false;

        for (var i = 0; i < hands.length; i++) {
            if (!this.getIsBust(i)) {
                goodHand = true;
            }
        }

        return goodHand;
    }
}


function main() {
    var playCurrentHand,
    playerSplits = false,
    deck1 = new Deck(),
    currentHandIndex = 0,
    play = true;

    //Create initial hands and deal first 2 cards
    var player1 = new Player(),
    dealer = new Player();

    while (play) {
        deck1.shuffle();
        player1.pushNewCard(currentHandIndex, deck1.popLastCard());
        dealer.pushNewCard(0, deck1.popLastCard());
        player1.pushNewCard(currentHandIndex, deck1.popLastCard());
        dealer.pushNewCard(0, deck1.popLastCard());

        //Print initial deal to player
        console.log("You were dealt a " + player1.getCard(currentHandIndex, 0) + " and a " 
                            + player1.getCard(currentHandIndex, 1));
        console.log("Dealer shows " + dealer.getCard(0, 0));

        //Play player's hand
        while (currentHandIndex < player1.getHandsLength()) {
            //Check for splits
            if (player1.getCardNumber(currentHandIndex, 0) === player1.getCardNumber(currentHandIndex, 1)) {
                if (confirm("You were dealt two " + player1.getCardNumber(currentHandIndex, 0) + "'s. Do you want to split them?")) {
                    player1.splitHand(currentHandIndex);

                    //Deal 1 card to each hand
                    player1.pushNewCard(currentHandIndex, deck1.popLastCard());
                    player1.pushNewCard(currentHandIndex + 1, deck1.popLastCard());
                }
            }

            playCurrentHand = true;
            while (playCurrentHand && !player1.getIsBust(currentHandIndex)) {
                if ((currentHandIndex > 0) || (player1.getHandsLength() > 1)) {
                    console.log("Your current hand is a " + player1.getScore(currentHandIndex));
                }

                // Player automatically stands on a 21
                if ((player1.getScore(currentHandIndex) < 21) && confirm("Would you like another card?")) {
                    player1.pushNewCard(currentHandIndex, deck1.popLastCard());
                    console.log("You draw a " + player1.getCard(currentHandIndex, (player1.getCardsLength(currentHandIndex) - 1))
                                        + " your new score is " + player1.getScore(currentHandIndex));

                    if (player1.getIsBust(currentHandIndex)) {
                        console.log("You bust on this hand");
                    }

                } else {
                    console.log("You stand on hand " + (currentHandIndex + 1) + " with a " + player1.getScore(currentHandIndex));
                    playCurrentHand = false;
                }
            }

            currentHandIndex++;
        }

        if (!player1.hasGoodHand()) {
            play = confirm("Do you want to play again?");
        } else {
            // Play dealer's hand
            console.log("The dealer was dealt a " + dealer.getScore(0));
            while (dealer.getScore(0) < 17 && !dealer.getIsBust(0)) {
                dealer.pushNewCard(0, deck1.popLastCard());
                console.log("The dealer draws a " + dealer.getCard(0, (dealer.getCardsLength(0) - 1)) + ". New score is " 
                                    + dealer.getScore(0));
            }

            // Show results of dealer's hand
            if (dealer.getIsBust(0)) {
                console.log("Dealer busts!");
            } else {
                console.log("Dealer stands with a " + dealer.getScore(0));
            }

            // Display results
            for (var i = 0; i < player1.getHandsLength(); i++) {
                if (!player1.getIsBust(i)) {
                    if (dealer.getScore(0) === player1.getScore(i)) {
                        console.log("You push on hand " + (i + 1));
                    } else if ((dealer.getScore(0) > player1.getScore(i)) && !dealer.getIsBust(0)) {
                        console.log("Dealer wins hand " + (i + 1));
                    } else {
                        console.log("You win hand " + (i + 1));
                    }
                }
            }

            play = confirm("Do you want to play again?");
        }

        if (play) {
            player1.initializePlayer();
            dealer.initializePlayer();
            currentHandIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}

//main();
```

Comment: As stated in the FAQ, please include the code you would like reviewed in the question.  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq#make-sure-you-include-your-code-in-your-question

Comment: Let's put it this way: If jsFiddle goes down, that like won't be relevant and your code won't get reviewed.

Comment: Sure thing. Added.

Comment: Hint:If you have that many conditional statements (`if`, `case` or `? :`) in your **Domain Object**s e.g. `Card` you are not doing OOP right.

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca Thanks for the feedback. Can you give me an example by refactoring one of the if statements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can you give me an example by refactoring one of the if statements?

Your `Card` object can be changed as follows:

Following your general style,

```
function Suit(name, sym) {
    this.getName = function () {
        return name;
    }

    this.getSymbol = function () {
        return sym;
    }
}

var hearts = new Suit("Hearts", "\u2665");
var clubs = new Suit("Clubs", "\u2663");
var diamonds = new Suit("Diamonds", "\u2666");
var spades = new Suit("Spades", "\u2660"); 
var suits = [hearts, clubs,  diamonds, spades];

function Rank(name, value) {
    this.getName = function() {
        return name;
    }

    this.getValue = function() {
        return value
    }
}

var ranks = [
    new Rank("Ace", 11),             
    new Rank("2", 2),             
    new Rank("3", 3),             
    new Rank("4", 4),             
    new Rank("5", 5),             
    new Rank("6", 6),
    new Rank("7", 7),
    new Rank("8", 8),
    new Rank("9", 9),
    new Rank("10", 10),
    new Rank("Jack", 10),
    new Rank("King", 10),
    new Rank("Queen", 10)
];

// Cards exist in Hands or Decks
function Card(suit, rank) {
    this.getCardSuit = function () {
        return suit.getName();
    };

    this.getCardNumber = function () {
        return rank.getName();
    };

    this.getCardValue = function () {
        return rank.getValue();
    };

}
```

And your deck creation accordingly changed from:

```
// Populate deck with 52 cards in order
for (var i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
    deckOfCards[i] = new Card(tempCardSuit, tempCardNumber);

    if (tempCardNumber < 13) {
        tempCardNumber++;
    } else {
        tempCardNumber = 1;
        tempCardSuit++;
    }
}
```

to:

```
for (var suitIdx = 0; suitIdx < suits.length; suitIdx ++) {
    for (var rankIdx = 0; rankIdx < ranks.length; rankIdx ++) {
        deckOfCards.push(new Card(suits[suitIdx], ranks[rankIdx]));
    }
}
```

Suit and Rank are **Value Objects**  from your domain. In which you can put more behavior. Now you can change relatively more easily from suit names to suit symbols for example.

As a rule of thumb if a property does not change during the life time of an object, do not calculate it in the object, you may pass it to the constructor.

Another OOP tip: If you are calling a number of methods of an object in a row, those code should probably go into that object.

```
this.getCard = function (cardPos) {
    return cards[cardPos].getCardNumber() + " of " + cards[cardPos].getCardSuit();
};
```

the portion:

```
card.getCardNumber() + " of " + card.getCardSuit();
```

can go into `card.toString()`

Another one: Methods should be short and do one specific thing which should be indicated by their names.
Your `Deck.shuffle()` methods is doing multiple things at once. It both populates the deck, but it also shuffles it afterwards. Populating the deck should move out of `shuffle` method.

The same is true for you `main()` method. 2 players and a deck are asking to be moved into a class `BlackJackGame` or some other name.

DRY: Don't repeat yourself. 
Repeating instances of `dealer.pushNewCard(0, deck1.popLastCard())` should move in to a function. Also note that that function can be a method of an object that contains both `deck` and `player`. Also note that method names containing implementation details like `push` or `pop` and the magic constant `0` are clues that that behavior needs to be encapsulated.

Comments such as this:

```
    // Display results
```

followed by a **chunk of code** should better be factored out into a method of its own, usually getting their names from the comment itself.

Comment: Marting Fowler's Refactoring book site
http://refactoring.com/
has a large catalog of refactorings.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed response and for the link of refactoring suggestions. It gives me stuff to chew on.